# How to set up WCF Self-Hosted REST service?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I'm trying to self-host some WCF RESTful services from my computer for consumption by machines on my local network. I have no experience with WCF and am largely a newb when it comes to this. I created a very basic, stripped down console app to see if I could get it working.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri httpUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:8090/");

        var host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(TestClass), httpUrl);
        var binding = new WebHttpBinding(); // NetTcpBinding();
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITestClass), binding, "testing");
        ServiceDebugBehavior stp = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
        stp.HttpHelpPageEnabled = false;

        host.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Commence with the testing!");
        Console.ReadLine();

        host.Close();
    }
```

Here's the service code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestClass
{
     [WebGet]
     [OperationContract]
    string TestMethod();
}

public class TestClass : ITestClass
{
    public string TestMethod()
    {
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

From a browser on my localmachine, I'm able to issue a simple get request and get

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">SUCCESS</string>
```

However, I don't seem to be able to ping this service from any browsers on my home network when I type in `http://<service machine's IP>:8090/testing/testmethod`.

Can anyone tell me what configuration I'm missing to enable the service to be visible to other machines on my local network without needing a DNS server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to register the port by using the `netsh` command:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8090/ user=\Everyone
```

Also make sure that you have disabled the firewall on the computer hosting this service. Otherwise, chances are that it might be blocking the traffic to port `8090`.

Comment: The `netsh` command was something I needed to learn, but it turns out that Windows Firewall was the issue after all. When I first launched the app, it asked me if I wanted to unblock it, which I did. I even went in and verified it, it showed 'mytestapp.svchost.exe' as being allowed through, but once I turned off the firewall, that's when the magic happened!

Answer (score 6):

here you go ..
a blog written by me.

[Self Hosted RestService](http://technease.blogspot.com/2013/08/self-hosted-windows-service.html)

Comment: Fantastic Shujaat, very helpful